# How to optimize MySQL queries with Joins and subqueries for large datasets (millions of rows)

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, left-join, large-data

I am attempting to join four large tables (35-200 million rows) of the international patent database (PATSTAT) into a top 15 of most cited patents matching a few requirements.
A first table (`t9`) lists citations from one group (family) of applications to another. 
Another table (`t1`) basically links everything together as is contains both family and application id's, and filing years
Tables `t2` and `tls209_appln_ipc` have are used to identify the `appln_id`'s to include.
The code that I have finally come to is the following:

```
SELECT t9.cited_docdb_family_id, COUNT(t9.cited_docdb_family_id) AS cited, t3.appln_id
FROM docdb_family_citation t9 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
t1.appln_id, t1.docdb_family_id from tls201_appln t1
LEFT JOIN tls204_appln_prior t2 on t1.appln_id=t2.appln_id 
WHERE
t1.appln_filing_year BETWEEN 2010 AND 2015
AND
t2.appln_id IS NULL
AND
t1.appln_id IN (SELECT distinct appln_id from tls209_appln_ipc where ipc_subclass_symbol in ("A61K", "C07K", "A61P", "Cl2N", "C07D", "Cl2P", "C07H", "C12Q", "C07J"))) t3 ON t9.cited_docdb_family_id=t3.docdb_family_id
GROUP BY t9.cited_docdb_family_id
ORDER BY cited DESC
LIMIT 15
```

The problem is that the query ran in the online web-based interface of PATSTAT does not converge before my session times out. Are there ways to improve the efficiency of this query?

-Edit-
The `tls_209_appln_ipc` contains 195 million rows of `appln_id` coupled with `ipc_subclass_symbol`. `appln_id`'s may occur zero or more times in this table. In my query I only need the `docdb_family_id`s if *any* of their linked `appln_id`s is linked to *any* of the `ipc_subclass_symbol`s I listed.

Comment: Have you considered to increase the wait_timeout slightly ? `mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option in the webbased PATSTAT interface, only select queries are accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from the earlier answers, final code that gave the result I was looking for:

```
SELECT t9.cited_docdb_family_id, t99.cited AS cited, t1.appln_id, t1.appln_nr_epodoc
        FROM docdb_family_citation t9 
INNER JOIN (SELECT cited_docdb_family_id, count(cited_docdb_family_id) as cited FROM docdb_family_citation GROUP BY cited_docdb_family_id) t99 
ON t9.cited_docdb_family_id = t99.cited_docdb_family_id
LEFT JOIN 
     tls201_appln t1
     on t9.cited_docdb_family_id = t1.docdb_family_id 
     WHERE
        t1.appln_filing_year BETWEEN 2010 AND 2015 and
        exists (select 1 from tls209_appln_ipc t209
                where t209.appln_id = t1.appln_id
                  and    t209.ipc_subclass_symbol in ("A61K", "C07K", "A61P", "Cl2N", "C07D", "Cl2P", "C07H", "C12Q", "C07J")
               ) and
        not exists (select 1 from tls204_appln_prior t2
                    where t1.appln_id = t2.appln_id 
                   )
GROUP BY t9.cited_docdb_family_id
ORDER BY cited DESC
LIMIT 15;`
```

note that the join with subquery `t99` is used to get the correct `cited` count

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT t9.cited_docdb_family_id, COUNT(t9.cited_docdb_family_id) AS cited, t3.appln_id
FROM docdb_family_citation t9 LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT t1.appln_id, t1.docdb_family_id
      from tls201_appln t1 LEFT JOIN
           tls204_appln_prior t2
           on t1.appln_id=t2.appln_id 
      WHERE t1.appln_filing_year BETWEEN 2010 AND 2015 AND
            t2.appln_id IS NULL AND
            t1.appln_id IN (SELECT distinct appln_id
                            from tls209_appln_ipc
                            where ipc_subclass_symbol in ("A61K", "C07K", "A61P", "Cl2N", "C07D", "Cl2P", "C07H", "C12Q", "C07J"
                                                         )
                           )
           ) t3
      ON t9.cited_docdb_family_id = t3.docdb_family_id
GROUP BY t9.cited_docdb_family_id
ORDER BY cited DESC
LIMIT 15;
```

This query has scope for optimization.  First, using subqueries in MySQL should be done sparingly, because the subquery is materialized.  You do not need a subquery here.  You can just chain the `left join` operations.  Second, `select distinct` is not useful in an `in` subquery.  In addition, often `exists` is faster.

I would start by rewriting this as:

```
SELECT t9.cited_docdb_family_id, COUNT(t9.cited_docdb_family_id) AS cited, t1.appln_id
FROM docdb_family_citation t9 LEFT JOIN 
     tls201_appln t1
     on t9.cited_docdb_family_id = t1.docdb_family_id and
        t1.appln_filing_year BETWEEN 2010 AND 2015 and
        exists (select 1 from tls209_appln_ipc t209
                where t209.appln_id = t1.appln_id AND
                      t209.ipc_subclass_symbol in ("A61K", "C07K", "A61P", "Cl2N", "C07D", "Cl2P", "C07H", "C12Q", "C07J")
               ) and
        not exists (select 1 from tls204_appln_prior t2
                    where t1.appln_id = t2.appln_id 
                   )
GROUP BY t9.cited_docdb_family_id
ORDER BY cited DESC
LIMIT 15;
```

For this query, you want the following indexes:  `tls204_appln_prior(appln_id)`, `tls209_appln_ipc(appln_id, ipc_subclass_symbol)`, `tls201_appln(cited_docdb_family_id, appln_id)`.

I'm not a fan of the `exists` and `not exists` in the `on` clause, but this seems to be the semantics you are looking for.  I strongly suspect there are better ways to write the query, but your question doesn't provide quite enough information.  The better way would be to aggregate the `t1` table first and then `left join` that result to the `t9` table.  However, the nested `left join`s and `exists` get confusing.

Comment: Thanks, firstly I added some additional explanantion on the role of `tls204_appln_prior` I think your suggestion on aggregrating the t1 table has much potential, I'm looking into it. Lastly I can't get the exists parts to run, but I have no experience with that whatsoever as i'm really new to SQL in general..

Comment: I got the suggested code to run (after minor fixes) and the query returns results in minutes! However, a new problem arose, the cited column has too high values, probably due to unwanted adding up. The highest value for `cited` in result is `1651` for family id `25133744` whereas `SELECT COUNT(cited_docdb_family_id )as cited FROM docdb_family_citation WHERE cited_docdb_family_id = "25133744"`returns `127`. Any clue on how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you created needed indexes so i'll pass indexing part.

- Using [views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/views.html) for your subqueries or main query and update them in background is an. This could help the timeout problems cause you will use views to select and background process will run your slow query.
- An option is [range partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-range.html) on appln_filing_year and may be a list partitioning on ipc_subclass_symbol... Year will not be a problem but ipc_subclass_symbol, i do not know how many unique data you have in this one but you can look for limitations [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-limitations.html). In your case partitioning will return results a little faster than normal.
- You can increase your [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) for mysql in my.cnf or run time. If you did not change it, it would be 28800 default. But personally i don't like this one.

i hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @mim., thanks for the tip, the views and wait timeout are unfortunately not an option, as the database only accepts SELECT queries. I'll try the partitioning, however as the subquery itsself runs in about five to ten seconds, I doubt if it will make a difference..

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to remove the inner sub query first, which could be done as a JOIN in the main sub query, using DISINCT to remove the duplicates this would otherwise create:-

```
SELECT t9.cited_docdb_family_id, COUNT(t9.cited_docdb_family_id) AS cited, t3.appln_id
FROM docdb_family_citation t9 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.appln_id, t1.docdb_family_id 
    FROM tls201_appln t1
    INNER JOIN tls209_appln_ipc t99 ON t1.appln_id = t99.appln_id 
    LEFT JOIN tls204_appln_prior t2 ON t1.appln_id = t2.appln_id 
    WHERE t1.appln_filing_year BETWEEN 2010 AND 2015
    AND t2.appln_id IS NULL
    AND t1.appln_id IN 
    AND t99.ipc_subclass_symbol IN ("A61K", "C07K", "A61P", "Cl2N", "C07D", "Cl2P", "C07H", "C12Q", "C07J")
) t3 
ON t9.cited_docdb_family_id = t3.docdb_family_id
GROUP BY t9.cited_docdb_family_id
ORDER BY cited DESC
LIMIT 15
```

If duplicate combinations of t1.appln_id, t1.docdb_family_id are possible over multiple rows of the tls201_appln table then I would suggest returning the rows unique key as well (so the DISTINCT will return distinct rows rather than distinct values).